# Align to the middle vertically and horizontally in Odoo's Qweb Reports

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, odoo, qweb, odoo-13

I'm trying to align vertically and horizontally to the center the content of the columns of the next example code:

```xml
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-4 text-center">
      <img t-if="o.company_id.logo" t-att-src="image_data_uri(o.company_id.logo)" style="max-height: 60px;" alt="Logo"/>
      <div>A String</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4" text-center>
      <div>Another String</div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-4">
      <div class="panel-body" style="border: 1px solid black">
          <div>Panel title <t t-esc="o.company_id.field_1"/></div>
          <div>Factura N°: <t t-esc="o.field_2"/></div>
          <div>ORIGINAL</div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Until now I've tried these classes: "row align-items-center", "col align-self-center", "align-middle" and the style "text-align:center;" none of these have worked. The class "text-center" does align horizontally but how can I achieve aligning in both vertically and horizontally? is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

The issue of vertical alignment is caused by wkhtmltopdf.
On Odoo 15 with wkhtmltopdf 0.12.5 (with patched qt)
Add style attributes to parent div will center the child content of p or span tags.

```
<div class="text-center" t-attf-style="display: -webkit-box; -webkit-box-pack: center; -webkit-box-orient: vertical;">
    <span t-field="o.text_field_to_be_centered"/>
</div>
```

The standard way of vertical alignment is using flex, but display: flex; is not recognized by wkhtmltopdf.
We need all 3 -webkit-box attributes to center vertically.
Last, class="text-center" is properly recognized for horizontally center alignment.